# glide unable to fetch dependency on buildkite CI pipeline

Tags: go, glide-golang, buildkite

I have a go service that uses glide for dependency management. I updated the version (in glide.lock file) for one of the packages used by the service. (The commit id is taken from master branch).

However, the CI job fails as it's unable to fetch the specified version. Below are some more details -

`[ERROR]  Failed to set version on github.com/xxx/yyy to 2262fbca7b493318ab33eb994940e4455641fa53: Unable to update checked out version`

Command used to update dependencies. (I added the clear cache command after it failed in first attempt, however it didn't help)

`glide cache-clear`

`glide install`

Any help, pointer to documentation that would solve the issue will be really helpful

Comment: glide is deprecate since several years, its unlikely you'll get it to work. Use modules.

Comment: Agree with @Volker - invest in converting to go modules.  Glide hasn't been maintained since mid-2019, and even then I would have advocated moving to go modules.

Comment: Not sure why the question was downmarked.